# How to solve mysql ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'UK_ability_shortname'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to add a unique key to a column and am getting an self explanatory error of

```
MariaDB [dnd]> ALTER TABLE ability
    ->   ADD UNIQUE INDEX UK_ability_shortname (shortname);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'UK_ability_shortname'
```

But the thing is that I cannot see any duplicates

```
MariaDB [INFORMATION_SCHEMA]> select * from INNODB_SYS_INDEXES WHERE NAME LIKE 'UK_%';
+----------+---------------------------------+----------+------+----------+---------+-------+
| INDEX_ID | NAME                            | TABLE_ID | TYPE | N_FIELDS | PAGE_NO | SPACE |
+----------+---------------------------------+----------+------+----------+---------+-------+
|     1733 | UK_food_food                    |      563 |    2 |        1 |       4 |   558 |
|     1737 | UK_type_type                    |      565 |    2 |        1 |       4 |   560 |
|     2077 | UK_invite_status_status         |      763 |    2 |        1 |       4 |   752 |
|     2586 | UK_tool_class_name              |     1093 |    2 |        1 |       4 |  1082 |
|     2591 | UK_food_drink_lodging           |     1097 |    2 |        2 |       4 |  1086 |
|     2595 | UK_lifestyle_expenses_lifestyle |     1100 |    2 |        1 |       4 |  1089 |
|     2691 | UK_weapon_name                  |     1173 |    2 |        1 |       4 |  1162 |
|     2692 | UK_weapon_property_name         |     1174 |    2 |        1 |       4 |  1163 |
|     2696 | UK_ability_name                 |     1183 |    2 |        1 |       4 |  1172 |
+----------+---------------------------------+----------+------+----------+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas what else I can check to find out why the DB thinks there is a conflict in name or am I exceeding some index name limit?

The table definition that I am trying to alter.

```
CREATE TABLE `ability` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `shortname` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_ability_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Page 175'
```

Using: Server version: 10.0.15-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Let me know if I can provide any other information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message means there are at least two rows that have the same value for the column `shortname` (`''`: the empty string). MariaDB consequently cannot create a *unique* index on that column. Search for any (other) duplicate values in the column with this query:

```
SELECT
    shortname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM
    ability
GROUP BY
    shortname
HAVING
    COUNT(0) > 1
```

Comment: DOH misread the error and assumed index name was the duplicate. Thank you

Comment: Can I take a moment to express the love I feel for Mysql error messages? Thank you for posting this.